# Installing @angular/core@2.3.1 with angular2-universal@2.0.10 peer dependency issue

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular-universal

I have followed [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) tutorial to get angular2 up and running with ASP.NET Core.

I have upgraded the angular packages to version 2.3.1

Now **angular2-universal@2.0.10** complains about a peer dependency of **zone.js@0.6.21**

[image]

If I install **zone.js@0.6.21** via **npm** **@angular/core@2.3.1** complains about a peer dependency of **zone.js@0.7.2**

[image]

Is **@angular/core@2.3.1** and **angular2-universal@2.0.10** not compatible as they depend on different versions of the **zone.js** package?

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the application?  As far as I've seen so far, zone.js is pretty forgiving with the versions, so if you have the higher version, it should still work.  Otherwise, you'll have to wait until angular2-universal updates to use the newer zone.js version or install an older version of angular/core that uses the same zone.js version.

Comment: Yes after struggling with a different issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244137/asp-net-core-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified I was able to run the application with no issues so far.