# ASP.NET Core The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, webpack-dev-middleware

I have followed [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) tutorial on getting angular and ASP.NET Core running together. The initial build worked fine but after updating angular packages I am receiving the following error on startup of the application(I also had to reinstall nodejs in the process, not sure if this is related):

The error is on the following line:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
    HotModuleReplacement = true
});
```

[image]

[image]

The error itself does not provide me with any usefull information to track down the issue.

I get a:

> System.AggregateException => Count = error CS0103: The name
>   'InnerExceptionCount' does not exist in the current context

Under InnerExceptions it lists the following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file
>   specified    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance..ctor(String
>   entryPointScript, String projectPath, String[] watchFileExtensions,
>   String commandLineArguments, ILogger nodeOutputLogger, IDictionary2
>   environmentVars, Int32 invocationTimeoutMilliseconds, Boolean
>   launchWithDebugging, Int32 debuggingPort)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance..ctor(String
>   projectPath, String[] watchFileExtensions, ILogger
>   nodeInstanceOutputLogger, IDictionary2 environmentVars, Int32
>   invocationTimeoutMilliseconds, Boolean launchWithDebugging, Int32
>   debuggingPort, Int32 port)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesFactory.CreateNodeInstance(NodeServicesOptions
>   options)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesFactory.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.CreateNewNodeInstance()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.GetOrCreateCurrentNodeInstance()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.d__10`1.MoveNext()}

If someone can point me in the direction to get more information from the Error would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is unable to find node.exe. I saw the same error after installing Node for the first time. It was because installing Node modified the system Path and the new Path wasn't getting picked up by IIS. I had to reboot my server and it was then able to find the node exe.

Comment: After a restart all was well.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have the latest NPM installed. This solved my problem.